# Receive Instagram stories that mentioned/tagged my business account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'd like to get all stories that mentioned or tagged my business account,
but exactly in stories. I can get posts via tags endpoint of Facebook graph API, but it doesn't include stories. And also I checked the mentions endpoint but seems it does not include stories too.

So, is there any public or maybe private API that can help to receive or I can get to know that some users mentioned or tagged my business account in their stories?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official API which supports mentions in IG Stories at this time

> Mentions on Stories are not supported.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/mentions/

Comment: even Hashtags are not supported? @andrew-l

Comment: Hashtag API is different https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/

Answer (score 0):

You can get story mentions by webhook if you have an Instagram professional account

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/story-mention/